# Workflow error Purchase requisition

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have created a purchase requisition which has to go through a workflow for approval.It gives me the following when i click on it .

Error executing code: SysWorkflowFormControls (object) has no valid runable code in method 'getActionBarContentForOriginator'.

```
(C)\Classes\SysWorkflowFormControls\getActionBarContentForOriginator
(C)\Classes\SysWorkflowFormControls\showOriginatorContent - line 19
(C)\Classes\SysWorkflowFormControls\updateControls - line 76
(C)\Classes\SysSetupFormRun\updateWorkflowControls - line 4
(C)\Classes\Info\formNotify - line 30
(C)\Classes\FormRun\selectControl
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is in Classes\SysWorkflowFormControls\getActionBarContentForOriginator  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install your ms dax 2009 sp1 to get rid of that error.

In case you dont want to install SPI to get rid of this error,
you could simply remove the datetime2str method.

For eg,
you could write “datetime2str(lastActionDateTime, DateFlags::FormatAll)” as “lastActionDateTime”.
Make sure you do these changes in three places in SysWorkflowFormControls Class.